# join with a group by?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table called rc_language_type_table with:

```
id language
1 english
2 Xhosa
3 afrikaans
```

etc
then i have a table rc_language_type_assoc_table with:

```
profile_id | language_type_id |
+------------+------------------+
| 3 | 1 | 
| 13 | 1 | 
| 15 | 1 | 
| 16 | 1 |
```

where i have profiles and each profile is connected to a language id in a 1 to many
so then i did:

```
select *,count(*) from rc_language_type_assoc_table group by language_type_id;
+------------+------------------+----------+
| profile_id | language_type_id | count(*) |
+------------+------------------+----------+
| 3 | 1 | 96 | 
| 3 | 2 | 19 | 
| 3 | 3 | 18 | 
| 64 | 4 | 51 | 
| 94 | 5 | 10 | 
| 37 | 6 | 26 | 
| 3 | 7 | 21 | 
| 3 | 8 | 4 | 
| 3 | 9 | 6 | 
| 88 | 10 | 4 | 
| 3 | 11 | 3 | 
+------------+------------------+----------+
```

what i want now is: instead having the language_type_id i want to display the actual language...how would i do this please???

i tried:

```
select *, count(*) 
from rc_language_type_assoc_table, rc_language_type_table 
group by language_type_id 
where rc_language_type_assoc_table.language_type_id = rc_language_type_table.id;
```

but i get a syntax error...
please help??

thank you

Comment: It's easier if you show us the sql structure and put everything neatly in code blocks.

Comment: It's also easier to get an answer if you accept answers to your other questions.

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY should be "after" the WHERE statement and not before

```
select *, count(*) 
from rc_language_type_assoc_table, rc_language_type_table 
where rc_language_type_assoc_table.language_type_id = rc_language_type_table.id
group by language_type_id ;
```